# How to count the number of values in a row based on condition - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of elements in a row and subtract a value based on the previous element. I can do it in a for loop, but it is too slow. I want to charge a $7 fee every time either 0 or 2 appears in the Target column, but not if the previous Target is equal to the current target. $0 fee for Target == 1, and $7 fee if new target appears that is not 1 or the current target. I have Target in my df, but i want to calculate Fee. Example on df

input:

```
df.head(10)

Target   Fee
1         0
1         0
1         0
0        -7
0         0
0         0
2        -7
2         0
1         0
2        -7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['Fee'] = (df.Target.diff().ne(0) & df.Target.isin([0,2])) * (-7)
```

Output:

```
   Target  Fee
0       1    0
1       1    0
2       1    0
3       0   -7
4       0    0
5       0    0
6       2   -7
7       2    0
8       1    0
9       2   -7
```